# emscripten pass var through emscripten_main_loop_arg

Tags: loops, parameter-passing, emscripten

I need to pass some var through: `emscripten_set_main_loop_arg`.
in the example below?

Prototype:

```
extern void emscripten_set_main_loop_arg (em_arg_callback_func func, void *arg, int fps, int simulate_infinite_loop);
```

How can do that ?

```
void foo( int x,int y ) ;

int main ( void )
{
 int x=10;
 int y=10;

 emscripten_set_main_loop_arg(foo, ?? , 60, 1); // ?? (void *)

 while(1) { foo(x,y); } ;

 return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a pointer to struct as `void*`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

typedef struct foo_arg {
  int x;
  int y;
} foo_arg;

void foo( void* arg_ ) {
  foo_arg* arg = arg_;
  printf("%d, %d\n", arg->x, arg->y);
}

int main ( void )
{
  int x=10;
  int y=100;

  foo_arg* arg = (foo_arg*)malloc(sizeof(foo_arg));
  arg->x = x;
  arg->y = y;
  emscripten_set_main_loop_arg(foo, arg , 60, 1);

  return 0 ;
}
```